# How to specify if a header param is mandatory or optional in micronaut

Tags: java, micronaut

I am passing two headers in controller as below

```
@Header("x-correlationId") String correlationId,
@Header(name = "x-consumedBy") String consumedBy
```

where `x-correlationId` is mandatory and `x-consumedBy` is optional. I am not able to specify this.

In Spring we can specify `required=false`.

Tell us what happens instead.
It is taking both as mandatory.

If I specify `@Nullable` then it is always taking the value as null even if I pass the value

```
correlationId::12345:consumedBy:null
```

Answer (score 4):

@Nullable is the preferred way to flag an argument as allowing nulls. If that isn't working for you then there must be something else at play that I can't tell from the information provided. It definitely does work, we have many tests that assert that.

Answer (score 3):

By default `@Header` params are mandatory, but to make `x-consumedBy` as an optional header you can set [defaultValue](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.0.x/api/io/micronaut/http/annotation/Header.html)

```
fun index(@Header("x-correlationId") xCorrelationId :String,
          @Header("x-consumedBy",defaultValue = "") xConsumedBy :String): String {
    
}
```